# PHPExcel con muchos registros no funciona, que puede ser?

Tags: php, excel

Al querer exportar una tabla con PHPExcel, funciona todo bien cuando son pocos registros, pero cuando existe mas de 3000 registros, no descarga el archivo excel, se queda en Blanco, alguno que le suceda lo mismo?

Comment: Por favor añade mas información: ¿puedes añadir código fuente?, ¿la información es consistente = no tiene errores?

Comment: Pues mira, utilizo el siguiente codigo:

Comment: actualiza la pregunta con el código y demás información.

Answer (score 1):

El problema no puede ser la cantidad de registros. Asegurate primero de tener habilitado el debug, puede que tu pagina se quede en blanco por no tener habilitado el *"Mostrar Errores"*

Coloca las siguientes dos lineas en el comienzo de tu archivo PHP:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Ejecuta de nuevo el código y si te da algún mensaje de error postealo en la información de la pregunta.

Por otra parte lo que se me ocurre sin ver el código es que el archivo podría no estar generándose completo porque el servidor alcance el tiempo máximo de ejecución de PHP o que PHP no pueda usar la memoria suficiente para ejecutar tu script.

Para probar esto en tu entorno local modifica el php.ini y toca las siguientes opciones:

Primero aumenta el tiempo de ejecución aumentando el valor de la opción:

```
max_execution_time
```

Y luego aumentar el valor de la opción:

```
memory_limit
```

Luego de modificar las opciones reinicia apache o el servidor Web que uses e intenta ejecutar tu código.

Answer (score 0):

si estas descargando directamente un archivo .xls debes tener el header Content-Length, ej:

```
header('Content-Length: '.$length);
```

donde $length contiene el largo del archivo.